# Can't find some kernel logs that could be seen in previous macOS versions

Tags: sleep-wake, power-management, logs, kernel, hibernate

I am looking for the kernel log messages that are output during the macOS hibernation process. As an example:

```
8/20/14 11:58:40 AM kernel  wired_pages_encrypted 60968, wired_pages_clear 39229, dirty_pages_encrypted 0
8/20/14 11:58:40 AM kernel  hibernate_write_image done(e00002eb)
8/20/14 11:58:40 AM kernel  sleep
```

I have looked through the Console, `syslog` and `log stream --debug --info --signpost` but I have not been able to find logs like this when my M2 MacBook Air (Ventura) goes into hibernation. The users of the questions listed below were able to find these log messages and included them in their post. However, it seems most of these posts are from between 2011-2014 and I haven't been able to find any posts containing these logs since then. However, I believe they are still being logged because I can still the log messages written in the most recent XNU open source code. e.g. `HIBLOG("hibernate_write_image done(%x)\n", err);` can be found in https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/xnu/blob/main/iokit/Kernel/IOHibernateIO.cpp. Has Apple changed the location of where these log messages appear? Is there a way I can still see them using another application/command or by changing a file e.g. /etc/asl.conf? Thanks

(Posts containing these logs)

[Mavericks sleep/hibernate causes high fan activity](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114593/mavericks-sleep-hibernate-causes-high-fan-activity)

[MacBook Pro wakes immediately after sleeping](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/105970/macbook-pro-wakes-immediately-after-sleeping)

[Why does my iMac take so long to go to sleep?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/142297/why-does-my-imac-take-so-long-to-go-to-sleep)

[Why does my MacBook Pro take so long to go to sleep?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19574/why-does-my-macbook-pro-take-so-long-to-go-to-sleep)